# How to Reject Promise in _.each loop

Tags: javascript, promise, lodash

How to reject the promise from the _.each loop, it is never reaching `document.write('Failed');`. Are there any better functions in lodash to handle this situation.

```
function check(){
  return Promise
      .all(
    [
      Promise.resolve([1,3,4]),
      Promise.resolve([0,4,3]),
      Promise.resolve(undefined)
    ]).then(function(results){
      return _.each(results, function(result){
         return _.each(result, function(value) {
          // should reject when value is 0
          if(!value){
            return Promise.reject();
         }
        });
      });

    });
    }

check().then(function(){
    document.write('All Success');
    }, function(){
    // Never reaching this code.. :(
     document.write('Failed');
    });
```

Here is the [plnkr.co link](https://plnkr.co/edit/3o9VfFYGuDEtu7Vz818L)

Comment: You are returning from the `each` callback, not from the `then` callback. Use a proper loop instead of lodash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to create a new promise in the `then` callback and return it. The point of promises is to allow you to write asynchronous code in a more 'synchronous-like' way. What you want to do in your `then` callback is to throw an error:

```
function check(){
  return Promise
      .all(
    [
      Promise.resolve([1,3,4]),
      Promise.resolve([0,4,3]),
      Promise.resolve(undefined)
    ]).then(function(results){
      return _.each(results, function(result){
         return _.each(result, function(value) {
          // should reject when value is 0
          if(!value){
            throw new Error();
         }
        });
      });

    });
    }

check().then(function(){
    document.write('All Success');
    }, function(){
    // Never reaching this code.. :(
     document.write('Failed');
    });
```

This will cause a rejection in the promise chain.

Answer (score 2):

The `_.each()` function returns the list in the first parameter and cannot be broken out of, according to the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

To achieve what you want, try using the `for...of` loop as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
function check(){
  return Promise
      .all(
    [
      Promise.resolve([1,3,4]),
      Promise.resolve([0,4,3]),
      Promise.resolve(undefined)
    ]).then(function(results){
      for (let result of results) {
         for (let value of result) {
          // should reject when value is 0
          if(!value){
            return Promise.reject();
         }
        });
      });

    });
    }

check().then(function(){
    document.write('All Success');
    }, function(){
    // Never reaching this code.. :(
     document.write('Failed');
    });
```

If you insist on using the `_.each()` loop you will never be able to break out of the loop when it hits the first rejection, so I wouldn't recommend that approach. However, you could declare a variable just before the first loop that initially contains a resolved promise, replace it with a rejected promise if the `!value` check passes and then return this variable after the loop at the end of the final `then()`.

Comment: Looking for lodash based approach for this situation. As the data, I deal with in little complex.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Promise.all` again, combined with `flatten` and `map`

```js
function check(){
  return Promise
  .all(
    [
      Promise.resolve([1,3,4]),
      Promise.resolve([0,4,3]),
      Promise.resolve(undefined)
    ]).then(function(results){
      return Promise.all(_(results).flatten().map(result => {
        if(result === 0) return Promise.reject()
      }))
      
    });
}

check().then(function(){
    document.write('All Success');
     //lert("all success");
    }, function(){
     document.write('Failed');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Also you could use `some`

```
function(results){
  return Promise.all(results.map(result => {
    if([].concat(result).some(value => value === 0)) {
      return Promise.reject()
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the `result` is an object, I mean, In the example `Promise.resolve([1,3,4])`, what if it is `Promise.resolve([{},{},{}])`.

Comment: @bash How do you want to compare objects to 0?

Comment: My logic with in the function is little complex and the rejection criteria is different. you have proposed 2 solutions `Promise.all(_(results).flatten().map(result` and `[].concat(result).some`. will they apply will objects?

Comment: I'd say yes. The structure of the code has nothing to do with the logic you want to apply. You simply need to replace criteria (`value === 0`) with the one you have. `if(isInvalid(result)) return Promise.reject()` or `.some(isInvalid)` where `isInvalid` is a function that applies any logic you want.